# Stream Rest API HTTP Response in Node.js & Express

Tags: node.js, rest, express, stream

I am creating a Rest API in Node.js and Express. It connects with remote HANA database & execute one query. Now I want to stream HTTP response so that I can send it to browser into chunks, rather than sending it completely since it's a very large data.

I tried something which is giving me no output. I don't know the reason. If I send the complete response to browser using response.send (data), it's working fine. But streaming is now working.

I have added code snippet below.

```
const express = require("express");
const APP = express();
const HANA_DB = require('hdb');
const BODY_PARSER = require("body-parser");

start();

function start() {
    startServer();
    initializeExpress();
    APP.get("/data", function(request, response) {
        var connection = HANA_DB.createClient({
            host     : "hostname",
            port     : "port",
            user     : "username",
            password : "password"
        });
        connection.on('error', function (error) {
            console.log("Error in database connection...");
        });
        connection.connect(function (error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Error in database connection...");
                return;
            }
            var query = "SELECT * FROM TableName";
            connection.exec(query, function(error, result) {
                if(error) {
                    response.send("Getting error while fetching result...");
                    return;
                }
                //response.send(data);
                var datalength = 0;
                request.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    datalength += chunk.length;
                    console.log("DATA EVENT: " + datalength);
                    response.send(datalength);
                })
                .on('end', function() {
                    console.log("END EVENT: " + datalength);
                    response.send(datalength);
                });
            });
        });     
    });
};

function initializeExpress() {
    APP.all('/*', function(request, response, next) {
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
        response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
        next();
    });
    APP.use(BODY_PARSER.json());
    APP.use(BODY_PARSER.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
};

function startServer(config) {
    var server = APP.listen("8081", function(error) {
        if(error) {
            console.log("Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8081");
            return;
        }
        console.log("Server is listening at - 127.0.0.1:8081");
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the logic you are using is wrong for the streaming the data.

Use **res.write** instead of **res.send** and you also have to read streaming data from your database instead of one time **connection.exec**

I am giving you an example code where you will get some idea about streaming data in Expressjs.

```
var http = require( 'http' );

http.createServer( function ( req, res ) {
res.writeHead( 200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
    'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff'
} );
res.write( 'Beginning\n' );
var count = 10;
var io = setInterval( function () {
    res.write( 'Doing ' + count.toString() + '\n' );
    count--;
    if ( count === 0 ) {
        res.end( 'Finished\n' );
        clearInterval( io );
    }
}, 1000 );
} ).listen( 8000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here `request.on('data',`. `request` refers to the browser request.

You cannot use streaming with `.exec()`, because the callback function of `exec` is called with the rows as parameters.

To use [streaming](https://github.com/SAP/node-hdb#streaming-results), use the `.execute()` method, which passes a resultset to the callback function.

I never used `hdb`, so I cannot give the code to use.

Comment: Do you mean to say to that i should set data & end event with result returning by query ? I tried it, but it's saying that result.on is not a function. How it would be possible, because result is not a writable stream.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I tried .execute method and i it's working for me. But now i am facing issues with sending chunk data to browser in data event. I am trying response.send(chunk) which giving error "Can't set headers after they are sent". It seems response.send(chunk),i can execute only one time. If it is, then how i will send chunks to browser in data event.

Comment: @DeveshM As I said, I never used `hdb`, so I'm sorry I cannot help you further.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. But i am not getting any clue on what i am looking for. Now I am able to stream results for both Hana & Oracle. But i am not able to send chunk data to browser back in data event. Can you guide me whether is it worth to send chunk data every time or should i send it to browser after loading complete data which i gets in end event of stream ?